# How can I place a button half on cardview and half on parent layout

Tags: android, button, layout, android-cardview

This is what I tried. But the button appears beneath the card. Can someone tell how can I make the button visible above the card. This represents a row in a recycler view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pList"
        card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap Button and Card positions into this xml layout file. You should also set an elevation to your Button, say, 4dp.`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pList"
    card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`

    <Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
   />
```

Comment: nice answer... very difficult question ever :)